# Tap on Response from Google Search Places API in Ionic

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

I am developing android Application using Ionic framework and I am using map in it and also put a search box. However when I search for places in textbox, the location appears as dropdown but unable to select it using tap or click in my android phone. Can anybody help to how to select location by tapping on it in device? Here is the screen shot of my phone. I want to select location by tapping on it but unable to do so.

[image]

here is my html code :

```
    <div class="phl">
        <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box" ng-model="vm.location.formatted_address">
    <div id="map"></div>
```

here is my controller code:

```
    var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a change event for input box

```
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box" ng-model="vm.location.formatted_address" ng-change="disableTap()">
```

Then add this code in the function

```
function disableTap() {
    var container = document.getElementsByClassName('pac-container');
    angular.element(container).attr('data-tap-disabled', 'true');
  }
```